# can you help me with this java program?

Tags: java, swing

I just started using swing and events
what I wanted was a basic program where there is a button in a window and when you click on the button an oval moves around the screen for  time,like wanted to be like animated.
This is what I did for it

```
package testmode;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Ainmationtester implements ActionListener {

JFrame frame;
JButton Button;
int x = 30, y = 30;

Ainmationtester tester = new Ainmationtester();
Ainmationtester.MyDrawPanels test = tester.new MyDrawPanels();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stubc
    Ainmationtester test = new Ainmationtester();
    test.go();

}

public void go() {
    frame = new JFrame("Aniamtor");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    Button = new JButton("CLick me to Animate");
    Button.addActionListener(this);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, Button);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, test);

}

public class MyDrawPanels extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        g.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
        test.repaint();
    x++;
    y++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: *"This is what I did for it.."*  Umm.. OK.  And where did you get stuck with it?  *"can you help me with this java program?"*  Sure, but you'll need to be specific about where you're stuck, and ask a more specific question.  Hear that sounds like *"Can you finish my codez?"*

Comment: could you specify where your problem is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote an example based on your code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Ainmationtester implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JButton Button;
    int x = 30, y = 30;
    MyDrawPanels draw = new MyDrawPanels();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ainmationtester test = new Ainmationtester();
        test.go();

    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame("Aniamtor");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        Button = new JButton("CLick me to Animate");
        Button.addActionListener(this);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, Button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, draw);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class MyDrawPanels extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        x += 5;
        y += 5;
        frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

The final `run` screenshot is the following

[image]

[image]
Hope that helped

Comment: I think he wants a simple Thread/Timer with a for/while loop that animates the ball. Also it would be great if you could explain to him what you changed and why his code didn't work. Because otherwise, he doesn't learn anything from it. (except he really compares his with your code and looks for the errors, but you can't rely on he doing that I think :P)

Comment: thank you for giving me your time. But can you please tell me what is wrong with my program,what is the error.Couldnt i run a loop in eventhandler method,cant i run the repaint in a loop?

Comment: @NitinSekhar Your loop wouldn't produce any visible animation. (It would have been too fast) You could use [Multithreading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) for that. The main error why your code didn't even run was because you got a `StackOverflowError` because of the line `Ainmationtester tester = new Ainmationtester();`. You basically created a new instance of Ainmationtester every time you create one.

Comment: of course, but the loop maybe is not necessary,       for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            Graphics g = draw.getGraphics();
            g.clearRect(0, 0, draw.getWidth(), draw.getHeight());
            draw.update(g);
        }
//        frame.repaint();    when you need repiant, firstly make sure to clear the graphic.